merge two ParamMap angular
I have the following code that works fine:
let urlParameters = combineLatest(
  [this.route.params, this.route.queryParams], (params, queryParams) => ({
      ...params, ...queryParams
}));

urlParameters.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params["type"]);
});

in the result I have new object and can access as params["type"]
but can I do the same with queryParamMap and paramMap?
like:
let urlParameters = combineLatest(
  [this.route.paramMap, this.route.queryParamMap], (params, queryParams) => ([
    ...params, ...queryParams
]));

urlParameters.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.get("type"));
});

and I can use ParamMap methods like params.get("type")

First access the keys using paramMap.keys, then loop these values and store them in a temporary object finalParams (do this for all map value you want to merge, here it is paramMap and queryParamMap), then we can use convertToParamMap from @angular/router to convert it to param map, with both the merged values.
The paramMap is a custom class ParamMap - Source Code and not the default Javascript map, hence, we need to recreate it with the respective properties to merge them.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngc-child',
  template: 'Child:<p>Param: {{params.id}}</p>',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  params: any;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let urlParameters = combineLatest([
      route.paramMap,
      route.queryParamMap,
    ]).pipe(
      map(([paramMap, queryParamMap]) => {
        const finalParams = {};
        this.mapParams(paramMap, finalParams);
        this.mapParams(queryParamMap, finalParams);
        return convertToParamMap(finalParams);
      })
    );

    urlParameters.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result.get('id'));
      console.log(result.get('test'));
    });
  }

  mapParams(paramMap, finalParams) {
    const keys = paramMap.keys;
    keys.forEach((key: string) => {
      const allParams = paramMap.getAll(key);
      finalParams[key] = allParams?.length <= 1 ? paramMap.get(key) : allParams;
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

error Type 'ParamMap' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

@A.Gladkiy updated my answer

Note that in paramMap, a single key can have multiple values, so it might be better to use getAll instead of get and store the array of strings per key in the merged object.

The easiest way I think (in case we need to use ParamMap methods):
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
...
let urlParameters = combineLatest(
  [this.route.params, this.route.queryParams], (params, queryParams) => convertToParamMap({
      ...params, ...queryParams
}));

urlParameters.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.get("type"));
});



Here's a utility function that provides a facade over a list of ParamMaps.

has returns true if the key appears in any of the maps.
get returns the value from the first map it is found in, if any.
getAll combines the values from all maps, may contain duplicates.
keys contains a unique list of keys of all maps.

If you are querying for multiple parameters this may not be as efficient as creating a new map first then querying that, but it's simple and works for me.
export const combineParamMaps = (...maps: ParamMap[]): ParamMap => ({
  has: (name: string) => maps.find(m => m.has(name)) !== undefined,
  get: (name: string) => maps.find(m => m.has(name))?.get(name) ?? null,
  getAll: (name: string) => maps.reduce((all, m) => [...all, ...m.getAll(name)], [] as string[]),
  keys: [...new Set(maps.reduce((all, m) => [...all, ...m.keys], [] as string[]))]
});

To use in the original question:
let urlParameters = combineLatest(
  [this.route.paramMap, this.route.queryParamMap],
  (params, queryParams) => combineParamMaps(params, queryParams)
);

